# Function wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

pretty new to this... can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Notice:

> Function wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. This notice was triggered by the acf-block-css handle.

My code:

```
$css_path   = plugins_url( "css/style.css", __FILE__ );
$css_dir    = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "css/style.css";
$js_path    = plugins_url( "js/scripts.js", __FILE__ );
$js_dir     = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "js/scripts.js";


if( file_exists( $css_dir ) ) {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'acf-block-css' , $css_path, array(), filemtime( $css_dir ) );

}

if( file_exists( $js_dir ) ) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'acf-block-js' , $js_path, array('jquery'), filemtime( $js_dir ), true );
}
```

Comment: That notice is telling you that you're not using the correct hook to enqueue your assets. So use one, two or all of these hooks, depending on where would you like the assets be loaded: `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, `login_enqueue_scripts`.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress uses a system of so-called "hooks", which are functions that are run at specific points within the process of building the webpage for the browser.

The system runs like this:

- A style is supposed to be within the `<head>` portion of an HTML document.
- within the function that outputs the `<head>` portion, WordPress executes a function named `wp_enqueue_scripts`. (this is for the "frontend" portion of the website. On the "backend" portion, a function named `admin_enqueue_scripts` is executed, and on the login page, the function is named `login_enqueue_scripts`)

Within your own code, you can "inject" your own stylesheets into this function like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_awesome_additional_styles' );  
//the previous line essentially says "Hey Wordpress, when you output all your scripts and styles, 
//please do whatever is written in the function my_awesome_additional_styles
function my_awesome_additional_styles(){
    $css_path   = plugins_url( "css/style.css", __FILE__ );
    $css_dir    = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "css/style.css";
    if( file_exists( $css_dir ) ) {
       wp_enqueue_style( 'acf-block-css' , $css_path, array(), filemtime( $css_dir ) ); 
       //The previous line essentially says: "Hey Wordpress, output the link to this stylesheet, okay?"
    }
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) and [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/loading-css-into-wordpress-the-right-way--cms-20402?ec_unit=translation-info-language).
Happy Coding!